# how to set arrayList with string objects to a prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a java ArrayList of a datastructure (string name, string email). The task is, to save the list in the database. I have an approach in my mind to use a for loop and use statement.setString( i, name) etc. Is there any better solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I would use a class to describe a data structure rather than a list, however the way you are building the `statement` appears fine to me.

Comment: ArrayList of a datastructure? Do you mean a List containing objects of a class and this class has 2 properties name and email? right? Well, the logic you are thinking appears ok to me.

Comment: @Naved: Yes, i meant a list containing objects of a class. And thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're going to use plain JDBC, a batch statement might be useful to you:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO xx (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)");

for (MyStructure s : list) {
  stmt.setString(1, s.name);
  stmt.setString(2, s.email);
  stmt.addBatch();
}

stmt.executeBatch();
```

So the idea you already have seems good to me. You'll find more info here:

http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/